# How to output text to a screen, while also outputting Object Orientated buttons - Pygame

Tags: python, oop, pygame

```
#Importing Modules
import pygame
import sys
import random

#All pygame stuff under here
pygame.init()

#Font definitions
backFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",40)
titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("garamond", 100)
buttonFont = pygame.font.SysFont("garamond", 25)
bigFont = pygame.font.SysFont("garamond",100)

#Colour definitions
BackGray = pygame.Color('gray60')
screenGray = pygame.Color('gray80')
buttonGray1 = pygame.Color('gray40')
buttonGray2 = pygame.Color('gray50')
buttonGray3 = pygame.Color('gray30')
textColour = pygame.Color('navy')

#Screen size set
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#Class for the buttons set here
class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, colour, surface):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.colour = colour
        self.surface = surface

    def isPressed(self):
        mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_x = mouse_position[0]
        mouse_y = mouse_position[1]
        if mouse_x > self.x:
            if mouse_x < self.x + self.width:
                if mouse_y > self.y:
                    if mouse_y < self.y + self.height:
                        mouse_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                        left_click = mouse_click[0]
                        if left_click:
                            self.colour = (0,0,0)
                            return True
        self.colour = (230, 230, 230)
        return False

    def drawButton(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.colour,  (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.flip()

def FrontPage():
    #Back screen
    screen.fill(screenGray)

    #The background is defined here
    BinaryPage = []
    for i in range(0,15):
        BinaryString = ""
        for j in range(0,33):
            BinaryString += random.choice(["0","1"])
        BinaryPage.append(BinaryString)

    for i in range(0,15):
        screen.blit(backFont.render(BinaryPage[i], 1, BackGray), (0,i * 40))

    #The title is defined and printed here
    Title1 = titleFont.render("The Six", 10, textColour)
    Title2 = titleFont.render("Cipher", 10, textColour)
    Title3 = titleFont.render("Simulator", 10, textColour)
    screen.blit(Title1, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(Title2, (100, 200))
    screen.blit(Title3, (100, 300))

    #Text for the button
    buttonText = buttonFont.render("Continue", 10, textColour)
    screen.blit(buttonText, (115,405))

    #Where the buttons are defined and drawn
    ButtonBig = Button(100, 450, 120, 60, buttonGray1, screen)
    ButtonSmall = Button(105, 455, 110, 50, buttonGray2, screen)
    ButtonBig.drawButton()
    ButtonSmall.drawButton()


    #Pygame While loop
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ButtonBig.isPressed():
                print("Hello")
                break
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        clock.tick(60)
```

The above code runs a window that has 0's and 1's in a random order as the background, with the title of my program in the middle.

Then, there should be a button at the bottom, or a grey rectangle. However, when I try to .blit, or print, something onto the button frame, after I have drawn the button onto the screen, it does not appear.

Can anybody tell me why and how to fix it?
Or any alternatives of how to output text onto the buttons.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first create a separate `background` surface and blit all the background graphics which never change onto it (the numbers in the following example). In the main loop you can just blit this background to clear the screen.

To blit text onto a button:

1. Pass the text to the `__init__` method
2. create the button image (a pygame.Surface)
3. render the text
4. create rects for the image and the text (pass the center of the image rect to the text rect to center the text)
5. blit the text surface onto the image.

For the buttons I'd use [sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and put them into a sprite group, so that you can draw them simply by calling `sprite_group.draw(screen)`. Sprites need an [`image`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and a [`rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) attribute to work. Pygame rects have collision detection methods that you should use instead of writing your own. In this case we can use the `collidepoint` method and pass the `event.pos` to it.

```
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

FONT = pg.font.SysFont('garamond', 25)
SCREEN_GRAY = pg.Color('gray80')
BUTTON_GRAY = pg.Color('gray40')
TEXT_COLOUR = pg.Color('navy')


# Inherit from pg.sprite.Sprite. That will allow you to
# put the instances into a sprite group.
class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width, height, colour):
        super().__init__()
        # Create the image of the button.
        self.image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(colour)
        # A pygame.Rect will serve as the blit position.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Render the text.
        txt = FONT.render(text, True, TEXT_COLOUR)
        # This txt_rect is used to center the text on the image.
        txt_rect = txt.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        self.image.blit(txt, txt_rect)
        # Set the position of the image rect.
        self.rect.topleft = x, y

    def is_pressed(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # MOUSE... events have an event.pos attribute (the mouse position)
            # which you can pass to the collidepoint method of the rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                return True
        return False


def main():
    button_big = Button('big button', 100, 250, 120, 60, BUTTON_GRAY)
    button_small = Button('small button', 105, 455, 120, 50, BUTTON_GRAY)
    buttons_group = pg.sprite.Group(button_big, button_small)

    background = pg.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background.fill(SCREEN_GRAY)

    for i in range(screen.get_height()//40):
        for j in range(screen.get_width()//40):
            n = random.choice(['0', '1'])
            background.blit(FONT.render(n, True, BUTTON_GRAY), (j*40, i*40))

    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return
            if button_big.is_pressed(event):
                print('big')
            elif button_small.is_pressed(event):
                print('small')

        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        # Blit the images of the contained sprites onto the screen.
        buttons_group.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Here's a [sprite and sprite group tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13). Alternatively, you can use a list instead of a sprite group and iterate over the contained buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, is there something I need to add to the class definition to call a function from one of these object orientated buttons? As I have implemented the above code into my program, and now I can't seem to get it to call a function, it can only print into the Interpreter

Comment: You can call the function in the event loop if `button.is_pressed(event)` is True. A more sophisticated approach, that you can see in actual GUI frameworks, is to pass the function (callback function) to the button during the instantiation and then call it inside of the `is_pressed` method. I can add an example if you want.

Comment: Yeah, what I did was try an call the function, which is another pygame bit of code - which will lead to like the next screen. I called it in the event section of the while loop, and it returned a black screen, even though in the called function, I had filled the screen and displayed other buttons

Comment: And have you figured it out now or do you still need help? Maybe it would be better to post another question with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that I can take a look at your most recent code.

Comment: Right, I will strip away all the irrelevant bits of code and post a new question, thanks for the help